# Connect Gopro to raspberry pi with ubuntu mate

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, gopro

I am working on a project with Raspberry pi 3 and with Ubuntu mate on it. I need to connect a Gopro camera to raspberry pi and do a live stream. It would be a great help with some easy suggesstions.
Is it possible with a mini HDMI cable available for gopro?

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI on a Rpi is for output only, you cannot use this as input from your Gopro.

But it seems that you can access the GoPro via Wifi and VLC for a live stream as shown [here](http://m.wikihow.com/Stream-Your-GoPro-to-Your-PC-Using-VLC-Media-Player).  So you can use VLC player on your Pi to view this.

Or maybe you can use gstreamer as shown [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-camera/streaming-video-using-gstreamer)

Comment: Actually the main goal for me to use gopro for image processing. I need to  use it as an USB camera so that I can use the live images for further computations in image processing like tracking or object detection. Is there any possibility of using gopro for this purpose with HDMI? Or with the USB cable? I have done some research in which a person uses Auvidea B101 which has a HDMI input and as an output goes to the CSI camera port of the Raspberry Pi. I just want to find a much easier and less expensive way to do this. Please provide some help on this. thanks